# SQLDependency thread

Tags: c#, events, sqldependency

i am in the process implementing SQLdepenency i would like to know in case of Dependency Handler exeuctues will it spun a different thred from main Process ? What will happen when the event handler triggers? Do i need to worry about any multithreds issues?

```
public void CreateSqlDependency()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)DBFactory.GetDBFactoryConnection(Constants.SQL_PROVIDER_NAME))
        {
            SqlCommand command = (SqlCommand)DBFactory.GetCommand(Constants.SQL_PROVIDER_NAME);
            command.CommandText = watchQuery;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            //Create the callback object 
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(this.QueueChangeNotificationHandler); 
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            DataTable dataTable = DBFactory.ExecuteSPReDT(command);
        }

    }
    catch (SqlException sqlExp)
    {
        throw sqlExp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public void QueueChangeNotificationHandler(object caller, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
        Fire();
}
```

Comment: Side note, please use `throw;` and not `throw sqlExp;` or `throw ex;`. Also, if you're just re-throwing them without doing anything else with them (as in this example, although I would understand if your production code is more complex than this example) then why catch them at all? Just let them fall through.

Comment: to add some color to Dinah's comment, throw; is superior because it doesnt truncate your stack trace the way throw ex; does, see [this article](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000352.html) for more detail

Answer (score 3):

It works in a separate thread, but there is only one such thread for all notifications. Have a look at the SQLDependency section in [this article](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/)

Answer (score 0):

[SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) documentation on MSDN mention about possibility that the OnChange event may be generated on a different thread from the thread that initiated command execution.

You should read [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx) article from MSDN which explain similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It will spawn a new worker thread to wait for the dependency notifications--but that's what you want (otherwise your main program loop would be held up waiting for something that may never happen!).

The example code at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a52dhwx7%28VS.90%29.aspx) shows to how avoid issues where the worker thread that gets the dependency/query notifications doesn't have the right to update the UI; their method passes the task to the UI thread so it will succeed (see step #12).

Answer (score 0):

It does spawn in a different thread!! You can create a simple Windows Application to test this, and you'll see how the OnChange handler can't modify any UI controls directly (you'd get something like "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control XXX accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"). To overcome this, you call BeginInvoke.

Here's a simple Windows application to test SqlDependencies (I hope you can imagine the UI).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestSqlDependancies
{
public partial class SqlDependencyTester : Form
    {
        SqlDependency sqlDepenency = null;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlNotificationEventArgs msg;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public delegate void InvokeDelegate();
        void sqlDepenency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            msg = e;
            this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(Notify));
        }

        private void Notify()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + " - Notfication received. SqlDependency " + (sqlDepenency.HasChanges ? " has changes." : " reports no change. ") + msg.Type.ToString() + "-" + msg.Info.ToString());
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetDependency();
        }

        private void SetDependency()
        {
            try
            {
                using (TicketDataContext dc = new TicketDataContext())
                {
                    SqlDependency.Start(dc.Connection.ConnectionString);
                    command = new SqlCommand(textBox1.Text, (SqlConnection)dc.Connection);
                    sqlDepenency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    sqlDepenency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDepenency_OnChange);
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```